# Original features percentage composing PC1 in PCA

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, pca, feature-extraction

I used PCA to find 60 PC's:

```
N_comp=60 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = N_comp)
X_pca=pca.fit_transform(X_scale) #lower dimension data
eigenvalues=pca.components_
```

Now, I'm trying to find the contributions of my features (the columns of X data) to PC1 and PC2. For example, for PC1, I'd like to show a bar plot of the percentage of each of the top 10 features, where the x-axis would have the labels of the features.

something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz24K.png

I'm trying to do this in python, but can't figure out how to find the features names. For example what I did is sorting to find the top 10 features variables composing PC1 as:

```
N_elements=10
PC1=abs(eigenvalues[1,:])
PC1.sort(axis=0)
PC1=PC1[::-1]
PC1=PC1[0:N_elements]
PC1
```

Which results in

```
array([0.17040832, 0.16937861, 0.1683676 , 0.16544657, 0.16491703,
   0.16491679, 0.16168056, 0.16108829, 0.16034576, 0.16029183])
```

and plotting it:

```
plt.bar(range(N_elements), PC1, alpha=0.3, align='center')
plt.title('Contributions of variables to PC1')
```

but this results in X-axis of just numbers 0 to 9 (corresponds to 10 elements). How could I retrieve the names and put labels on the plot bar?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFdDt.png

Thanks so much!